# How to profile a Rails request with details?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, profiling

I have a page request which takes more than 12sec to render. i am using newrelic lite to track the performance of this application but, in my case, it's not very useful. It only shows one line :

```
PagesController#index 0.001  13,030 13030
```

So, not very useful. :) I remember a tool using I think `ruby-prof` which was good. You provided something like `?profiler=true` for a request and it gives you all the details with the time spend in method calls (not displaying the actual page in the browser). Unfortunately, I haven't managed to find it again.

Any ideas to have a more detailed profiler per request/page ?

Using : Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1.1, RSpec, New Relic RPM 3.3.0, Mongoid 2.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [rack-perftools_profiler](https://github.com/bhb/rack-perftools_profiler). I've used this for exactly what you're describing and it works well.

Comment: yeah exactly what I was looking for, (gif/pdf view is hard to understand),  thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right track.

With `gem 'ruby-prof'` and `gem 'newrelic_rpm'` in your `Gemfile`, you get a new option on your http://localhost:3000/newrelic page which says `Start profiling`. Each request on the newrelic page will now be a full profile not just a summary.